# MVC application cannot perform RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I'm new with javaEE development, i want to make simple "hello world" - spring,hibernate application, i already have mapped class to hibernate, dao classes etc... problem is that i would like to try my Controller which i dont know how to make it, but at first i have another question-> property: hibernate.dialect is deprecated -> is it wrong??? and is this cfg file good for postgresql?

hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/come_to_blog_db</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <mapping class="com.lime.model.User" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

but now my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUsers(ModelMap map) {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

}
```

hello world at localhost:8080 is working, but if i want acces to localhost:8080/user, it shows error 404, can anyone explain me what i'm doing wrong? shouldnt it redirect me to index page? thanks much :)

Comment: Why do you even have hibernate.cfg.xml file? Why don't you configure SessionFactory in Spring's context xml file? Also, where is your method that shows index page?

Comment: Probably because you don't have any mapping for /index. What's the URL displayed in the address bar after you get the 404?

Comment: brano: i checked some tutorials and all of them were configuring hibernate in that file so.., and method for index page is not exist because i created maven webapp and it automatically calls index.jsp when i acces homepage (localhost:8080) JB Nizet: oh yes maybe youre right, can you help me how to redirect to the working homepage? (localhost"8080)? thx

Comment: Because your method mapped to /user immediately redirects to /index. Why don't you answer the question?

Comment: the URL is still localhost:8080/user

Comment: I guarantee that the tutorials you are using are old. Try to find a tutorial written earlier than 2012-2013.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the wrong url. If your project name is WebProject, the url will be:

`localhost:8080/WebProject/users`

Comment: the problem was i didnt updated web.xml file and i didnt add a servlet, so i just solved my problem..thx for advices anyway guys

Answer (score 0):

`redirect:/index` will redirect you to the url `/index`(change the url in the browser),
 not to the view. You need to handle the url and resolve the view.

Add:

```
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(ModelMap map) {
        return "index";
    }
```

and if you have a view resolver, it will load the index page.

Comment: i edited my code to this but its still not working: @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUsers(ModelMap map) {
        return "index";
    }

Comment: @CharlieHarper You probably don't have a view resolver. See this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/